# How to report non-developer, non-security issue to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, bug-trackers

I have found a small, yet annoying issue with Facebook Page Ads (details below) and I would like to report this to Facebook. How can I do this?

Fifteen minutes of search lead me to only tools for reporting security vulnerabilities, developers API bugs and to some misleading texts in Facebook Help (where title and introduction says something like "*If you want to report a bug, you're in a right place*", but then only links to some texts follows and there is no link to any real bug reporting tool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `Facebook Survey` box, that any Facebook Pages Ads campaign runner my reach, by going to [New Page Insights](https://www.facebook.com/2222FacesCom?sk=insights), clicking on `...` buton in (right-top corner) and selecting `Send Feedback`.

But, I'm not sure, if this is what you've been looking for? And... I'm not sure, if anyone is reading this at Facebook side! :]